# How can i make an NSFW command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been following a discord bot tutorial, here is the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu6HuEUIuxI

Here is my current code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_nsfw()
async def hentai(ctx):
    r = requests.get("https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/hentai")
    res = r.json()
    em = discord.Embed()
    em.set_image(url=res['url'])
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

The error I get is as followed:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.\PycharmProjects\Kushina 2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\.\PycharmProjects\Kushina 2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.\PycharmProjects\Kushina 2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'url'
```

***Does anyone have a way of writing code for this command that works?***

Comment: first you should get url and check manually in browser to see what you get. It gives error 404 - so this url doesn't work any more. And Stackoverflow is not place to search working URL for you.

Comment: if you check main page from your link `https://nekos.life/` then you should see it loads some images. And if you check HTML for this page then you should see link to image like `https://cdn.nekos.life/neko/neko383.png`. And if you reload this page then you always see similar link but with different number. So you could use this link and add random number to create link to some image.

Comment: if you would watch video carefully then you should see it tests link `https://nekos.life/api/v2/endpoints` and this link still works. It shows all allowed links - and `/img` doesn't have `/hentai` any more. But works other links - ie. `https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/8ball`

Answer (score 0):

If you would watch video carefully then you should see (at time `1:50`) that author tests link

https://nekos.life/api/v2/endpoints

and this page shows allowed links in API.

If you test this link now in browser then you will see it still works but there is NO `hentai` on this list.

But there are other still working links. `smug', 'woof', 'gasm', '8ball', 'goose', 'cuddle', 'avatar', 'slap', 'v3', 'pat', 'gecg', 'feed', 'fox_girl', 'lizard', 'neko', 'hug', 'meow', 'kiss', 'wallpaper', 'tickle', 'spank', 'waifu', 'lewd', 'ngif`

ie.

https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/8ball